# Visual Studio C# webbrowser change one part of the url with an int?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to set one part of the URL.

Example:

```
https://thisisawebsite.com/id=someid&some&more&stuff&that&has&to&be&here
```

How would I make `"someid"` an int from my code? Is this even possible or what is the best way to do it?

Truly sorry for making such huge mistake! I forgot to add that I am trying to use Webbrowser.Navigate(url).

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of string concatenation.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int id = 9999;
string uri = string.Format("https.//thisisawebsite.com/id={0}", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
int someid = //Whatever your int value is
String SUrl = "https://thisisawebsite.com/id=" + someid;

Server.Transfer(SUrl, true);
```

Comment: If the downvoter could explain, that'd be great.  because this is working code I use in my project every day and is 100% accurate.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm guessing it was downvoted because you are concatenating strings with + instead of using String.Format.  Imagine how ugly this code will get when all of the URL parameters are added.

Comment: Ahhh...  Well, the original question only called for one variable.

Comment: While that is true, it's still a bad coding technique.  Since you said you use this code in your project every day, I would strongly suggest that you refactor it.